2D Transform not working (Newbie Question)
I'm trying to use a 2D transform on my website project to make an image move from off-screen on the left side to a place onscreen. I have tried everything I've read on W3 Schools and MDN Web Docs but nothing has worked. The image has remained completely static no matter what I do, and the transform doesn't play.
Here is my code:
.authorimage {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 2rem;
    transition: transform 3s;
    transform: translateX(-45rem);
}

Oddly, the only time the transform play is when I go into my web browser's inspect and unclick/click the CSS code for transform: translateX(-45rem); Then and only then does the transform do what it is supposed to do via W3 Schools. I've also consulted and altered my code many times via MDN Web Docs and nothing has worked. Can anyone help?

Transitions only apply to property changes. So when you render the page, go to dev tools and change your transform value to 0 you should see it moving but when your page renders .authorimage is already translated. Use an animation with @keyframes instead.

There is nothing to transition. The element is translated at the start and nothing changes that. Are you looking for CSS animation?

I think you may be confusing transition with animation.  Transition will interpolate between 2 styles.  Animation will actually have something move.


.authorimage {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 2rem;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-45rem);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
<div class="authorimage">Hello</div>



You could accomplish this with transitions, but you'll need to use 2 classes to transition between:


// Or a button or something
setTimeout(() => {
  document
    .querySelector('.authorimage')
    .classList.add('final');
}, 100);
.authorimage {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(-45rem);
}

.authorimage.final {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
<div class="authorimage">Hello</div>



